# Android - FrameLayout with a custom view requiring a constructor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.4-kitkat, android-relativelayout

What I am attempting to do is take a custom view (which is a constructor & onDraw method) and a set of controls in a RelativeLayout and display them together with-in a FrameLayout. My code currently gets to adding the overlay and crashes with a Null Pointer Execption but if I directly add the overlay and cut out the FrameLayout & custom view it works.

```
FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
SampleView sv = new SampleView(this, objectA, objectB, ObjectC), RESULTS);
RelativeLayout overlay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.analysis_overlay);

layout.addView(sv);
layout.addView(overlay);

setContentView(layout);
```

I assume there is a better way to do this and I've seen examples of a FrameLayout existing in xml but I didn't see anyway of setting the constructor via that method... So is there a better way of doing this that still allows custom view to have a constructor or did I mess somthing up with my current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to find an id of a layout resource.  Instead,  inflate your relative layout (the layout resource) and then add it.

```
FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
SampleView sv = new SampleView(this, objectA, objectB, ObjectC), RESULTS);
RelativeLayout overlay = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.analysis_overlay, layout, false);


layout.addView(sv);
layout.addView(overlay);

setContentView(layout);
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RelativeLayout overlay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.analysis_overlay);
> ```

- You can never find anything with id from `R.layout`. Use `R.id`.
- You can never find anything before `setContentView()` when using `Activity` `findViewById()`.

Call `findViewById()` on a view hierarchy that actually contains the overlay you want to find.

If you just want to inflate an XML layout, use `LayoutInflater`.